# I want to create a function which checks similarly named arrays for a certain value and correspondingly return values

Tags: python, numpy, function, if-statement

I want a function that searches for a number in similarly named arrays and then return specific values which correspond to the particular array it was found in.

I have written the following code which uses if and elif:

```
bf0 = np.arange(38,75,1)
for i in range(1,5):
    globals()["bf"+str(i)] = globals()["bf"+str(i-1)]+37
def func(x):
if x in bf0:
    return "x is in bf0"
elif x in bf1:
    return "x is in bf1"
elif x in bf2:
    return "x is in bf2"
elif x in bf3:
    return "x is in bf3"
elif x in bf4:
    return "x is in bf4"
```

Althought this works, is there any way I can simplify the code to fewer unrepetitive lines?

Comment: Unless you want to use `eval()` you would probbaly want to use dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

arrays = {}

for i in range(5):
    array_name = "bf" + str(i)
    start = 38 + i * 37
    end = 75
    arrays[array_name] = np.arange(start, end, 1)

def search_array(x):
    for array_name, array in arrays.items():
        if x in array:
            return f"{x} is in {array_name}"
    return f"{x} is not in any array"

result = search_array(45)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).